# how to show selected value in filter multi checkbox template as array of strings outside the kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am pretty new to Kendo UI. I have been working on an Asp.Net MVC web application where we use Kendo Grid and have a requirement of 
1) display the options that are selected in the Filter Multi Checkbox template on top of the grid as Array of strings. 
2) The array of strings must appear as buttons similar to the column headers that are groupable (feature that allows drag and drop of the column headers into the toolbar of the grid to group by that column)

For Eg: If i select options (Chai, Chang, Aniseed Syrup) from the multi checkbox filter "Product Name" column in the Kendo Grid, it should appear on top of the grid as shown in the image attached -
[Kendo Grid Multi Checkbox Options as Column Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFeFR.png)

Can someone please guide how to go about this?

Comment: Hi. Would modifying the FilterMenuInit event somehow help in this case?

Comment: Are you trying to make it function like the grid's native grouping function i.e. whatever the user selects from multi-select turns into a group?